# get only author name for revision SVN for Windows

Tags: svn, batch-file, command-line, post-commit, svn-hooks

I am writing post-commit-hook script for svn repository for windows.
I have a `.bat` file for this.

Now I want to get only the author name for a revision, how to do this?

I know `svn info -r revnumber` gives me information for particular revnumber.

```
Repository UUID: 65c289e3-30af-4e40-9b38-41a2938c897c
Revision: 25
Node Kind: directory
Last Changed Author: foolish
Last Changed Rev: 25
Last Changed Date: 2014-08-13 23:23:24 +0530 (Wed, 13 Aug 2014)
```

I want only the Last Changed Author from info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get author's username by running [`svnlook author -r %2 %1`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnlook.c.author.html).

- `%1`: repository path,
- `%2`: revision number created by the commit.

See [post-commit hook reference.](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit.html)

Comment: yes..! it worked. I missed to check svnlook, Thanks for help.
Just FYI, we have to mention repository location too with svnlook command.
`svnlook author -r %rev% %repos%`